# How to temporary disable Touch ID on iPad?

Tags: ipad, touch-id

On an iPhone SE, if I press quickly the power button few times I can disable temporarily Touch ID.

How can I temporarily disable Touch ID on and iPad 2018 in a similar way without rebooting the device? I'm basically searching for a panic button. I'm using iOS 12.

Comment: There is already a 'panic button' functionality in iOS; but it is for a panic situation, to dial an emergency number. What are you actually trying to achieve by this? If you simply want to be able to enter your passcode instead of using TouchID, then press the Home button with a fingernail, or glove, or... it will eventually ask for your passcode instead.

Comment: I know that a panic button exist. I know how to do that with Iphone SE. I'm asking about Ipad 2018. Even with LTE version it doesn't display that page where you can choose a medical card or call an emergency. If you really need a user case then let's say I want to sleep with a device turned on for quick access but I don't want my fingerprint be abused to unlock the device when I sleep. And no I don't want too use a freaking glove to temporarily disable Touch ID.